# PostgreSQL - Removing NULLS row and column from conditional aggregation results

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a query for a multidimensional table using conditional aggregation

```
select A,
   SUM(case when D = 3 then D end) as SUM_D1,
   SUM(case when D = 4 then D end) as SUM_D2)
```

The result:

```
A    SUM_D1  SUM_D2
-------------------
a1   100     NULL
a1   200     NULL
a3   NULL    NULL
a4   NULL    NULL
```

However, I would like to hide all NULL rows and columns as follows:

```
A   SUM_D1 
-----------
a1   100 
a1   200
```

I have looked for similar problems but they are not my expected answer.

Any help is much appreciated,

Thank you

Comment: Use `having` to filter for `IS NOT NULL` or `where` plus Derived Table. For not showing columns there's no way using plain SQL.

Comment: @dnoeth, Can you give me more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter all-NULL rows you can use HAVING

```
select *
from 
 (
    select A,
       SUM(case when D = 3 then D end) as SUM_D1,
       SUM(case when D = 4 then D end) as SUM_D2)
    ...
 ) as dt
where SUM_D1 is not null 
  and SUM_D2 is not null
```

Of course, if you got simple conditions like the ones in your example you better filter *before* aggregation:

```
select A,
   SUM(case when D = 3 then D end) as SUM_D1,
   SUM(case when D = 4 then D end) as SUM_D2)
...
where D in (3,4)
```

Now at least one calculation will return a value, thus no need to check for all-NULL.

To filter all-NULL columns you need some Dynamic SQL:

- materialize the data in a temporary tabke using Insert/Select
- scan each column for all-NULL `select 1 from temp having count(SUM_D1) > 0`
- dynamically create the Select list based on this
- run the Select

But why do you think you need this? It will be confusing for a user to run the same Stored Procedure and receive a different number of columns for each run.

Answer (score 2):

I think this does what you want:

```
select A,
       coalesce(sum(case when D = 3 then D end),
                sum(case when D = 4 then D end)
               ) as sum_d
from t
group by A
having sum(case when d in (3, 4) then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Note that this returns only one column -- as in your example.  If both "3" and "4" are in the data, then the value is for the "3"s.

If you want a query that returns a variable number of columns, then you need to use dynamic SQL -- or some other method.  SQL queries return a fixed number of columns.

One method would be to return the values as an array:

```
select a,
       array_agg(d order by d) as ds,
       array_agg(sumd order by d) as sumds
from (select a, d, sum(d) as sumd
      from t
      where d in (3, 4)
      group by a, d
     ) d
group by a;
```

Comment: Thank you, I think a having clause in your expression maybe helps me to hide NULL rows. but I think it is not possible for hiding an empty column.

Comment: @DuyHuynh . . . You cannot "hide" columns, unless you use dynamic SQL.  The columns are explicitly specified in the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1):

Null appear because the condition that's not handled by `case statement`

```
select A,
   SUM(case when D = 3 then D end) as SUM_D1,
   SUM(case when D = 4 then D end) as SUM_D2
 from
    Table1
 group by
     A
 having 
     (case when D = 3 or D = 4 then D end) is not null
```

As comment said if you want to suppress the null value.. You can use having to suppress null using `is not null`

Comment: The OP doesn't want to disply zero instead of NULL, he wants to suppress those rows/columns

Comment: Yes.. D have that both value and i miss the op want.. Op want to suppress those.. Not change value..

Comment: `having 
     D is not null` will not run, after aggregation there's no more individual D, must be in WHERE

Comment: In your expression, if 3 and 4 exist in D the having clause is always true, is it right? I think the null value in my case comes from the value D =3 and A = a3 does not exist

Comment: @DuyHuynh your `case when d= 3 or d=4` will show d and if no then value become `null` because you not handle the condition if `d != 3 or d != 4`.. And i filter that with having and of course a3 will not exist because he don't have condition met..

Answer (score 1):

I may have misinterpreted your question because the solution seems so simple:

```
select A,
   SUM(case when D = 3 then D end) as SUM_D1,
   SUM(case when D = 4 then D end) as SUM_D2)
where D is not null
```

This is not what you want, is it?   :-)

Comment: In my case, I think D is not null always true because D = {3,4}. The values is null because D=3 and A =a3 is null and so on.